# Apache Flink: How to deal with record with many fields?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am working with **.tsv** files that have **61** columns. I want to do some `DataSet` transformations, but the maximum column `Tuple` in **Flink** is `Tuple25`, containing **25** columns.

Is there a way to implement my own `Tuple` containing **61** columns? I tried extending the `Tuple` class, but as soon as I try mapping the lines of the .tsv file into a tuple, I get :
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The tuple type exceeds the maximum supported arity`

If I don't extend the `Tuple` class I am mapping the lines into tuples successfully, but I get an exception when I am trying to do some `DataSet` transformations like join:

```
ds1
            .join(ds2)
            .where(0)
            .equalTo(0)
            .writeAsText("./result.tsv", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
            .setParallelism(1);
```

Exception: `org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Specifying keys via field positions is only valid for tuple data types.`

Is there a way to implement custom `Tuple` class, or any other way to deal with these transformations?

Comment: Very nice question. My guess: don't do that. Otherwise we end up in a Tuple1024.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use your own custom POJO data type containing as many columns as you wish. Then, instead of using `.where(0)` and `.equalTo(0)` pass a custom KeySelector like so `.where((KeySelector<CustomDataType, String>) value -> value.getColumnN())`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good answer. In my case I just had to replace the lambdas with an anonymous classes and it worked as it should.